# How to stop Windows from TCP resetting on unrecognized SYN-ACK packets?

Tags: tcp, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to stop a Windows host computer from sending RST packets when a SYN-ACK has been received without a preliminary SYN from the host?

Is there a boolean registry entry for that? I prefer not to use external tools, but if it's the only solution please mention that.

However, for my purposes it's okay to disable that mechanism only for specific IP addresses, network interfaces or even specific ports if there's no other way.

I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Block the RST packets with Windows Firewall, perhaps?  Or send the SYN from a different MAC and IP address, one Windows doesn't know about?

Comment: How to block TCP packets with specific flagging like RST in Windows Firewall? I see only "high-level" rule options. And, maybe a better solution is to block all the traffic in one interface (since I have regular one and a loopback one) and use all inside with raw sockets? By the way, I didn't understand your second solution - if I will change the source addresses, isn't that meaning the answer will be delivered to an incorrect computer/interface?

Comment: Virtual machines are able to send and receive packets using their own MAC addresses, and they don't have problems with SynAttack protection, so it must be possible.  But I don't know exactly how they do it.

Comment: When and why do virtual machines need a solution for that?

Comment: Well, the host instance of Windows didn't generate the SYN packets coming from the virtual machine, so it seems directly analogous to your case.

Comment: Some of the networking capabilities of VMs are probably a kernel-space gaming, aren't they?

Comment: Quite possibly, though IIRC third-party winsock providers can be implemented in user mode.  It might be worth looking at the implementation of the various open-source VMs, e.g., Bochs.

Answer (score 0):

[Syn attack protection on Windows Vista, Windows 2008, Windows 7, Windows 2008 R2, Windows 8/8.1, Windows 2012 and Windows 2012 R2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/01/syn-attack-protection-on-windows-vista-windows-2008-windows-7-and-windows-2008-r2.aspx):

> As of Windows Vista and onwards (Vista/2008/Win 7/2008 R2/Windows 8/Windows 2012/Windows 2012 R2), syn attack protection algorithm has been changed in the following ways:
>
> 1) **SynAttack protection is enabled by default and cannot be disabled!**

Comment: It's not a SYN by the way... However, the reason I need to disable this mechanism is that I'm sending the SYN with a raw socket so the operating system don't know it. And of course, I don't want Windows to reset or close it when receiving the SYN-ACK. Is there a solution?